printf '%s\n' works in bash terminal but not python subprocess
This one seems simple enough, so I'm sure I'm just missing a minor detail. Still, searches haven't uncovered anything and the command I've using works verbatim in the terminal, so here we are.
I need to list all files in a directory with tens of thousands of files in it. Due to its size, I found printf '%s\n' *.* is far quicker to query for the folder contents than ls. Unlike ls, though, I need to be in the folder of interest first. That's fine, I can run cd path/to/folder & printf '%s\n' *.* successfully in the terminal.
If I try to do the same in my python script, though, the command returns no contents. It doesn't error, but nothing is returned. It also returns very quickly -- when I run the command in the terminal it still takes about a second or two to parse before returning the list of contents. Running the command in subprocess is near-instantaneous.
Other details:

Macbook Pro running Sonoma 14.6.1
Python v3.8.6
folder contains only .mp3 files (aside from hidden Mac files I ignore)

Here is an example of what I've tried:
cmd = ['cd', 'path/to/folder', '&', 'printf', "'%s\n'", '*.*']
result = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
directory_contents = result.stdout.decode("utf-8")

...I've tried changing up the use of quotes, using Popen and communicate instead of run, using '&&' instead of '&', adding shell=True, etc. If I change the command to a simple ls path/to/folder the subprocess command works fine and I receive a list of file names (eventually). What am I missing?

Hello! Have you tried os.listdir('path/to/folder')?

\n, in a Python string literal, becomes an actual newline character - not a backslash followed by 'n', which is what printf is looking for.  You either need to double that backslash, or make the literal containing it raw by putting a r in front of it.

@David: That wouldn't filter to things matching *.*, it would just get everything, but variations on that using the glob module or listcomps/genexprs over os.listdir/os.scandir would work.

@David oh perfect, this works! Since I was in the habit of using the terminal most of the time, I just went right to subprocess in my Python script without really thinking about whether python could natively do what I was attempting. As for ShadowRanger's point: I'm just avoiding any possible hidden files, but looking at the return from os.listdir() there doesn't appear to be any anyway. Thank you both!

You're trying to do shell things in a non-shell; & doesn't mean anything special outside of a shell, nor does *.*. You're also adding extra quotes you don't need, and inserting literal newline, not the escape sequence printf needs, because you pre-split your command line. Since the only reason you needed shell features was to change your directory, just let run do that for you with the cwd argument. Then use the glob module to get the files (because again, you're not in a shell, *.* won't expand). You can also use capture_output (since you're in 3.8, and it was added in 3.7) to simplify things:
import glob

path = 'path/to/folder'
# r in front of "%s\n" makes it a raw string, so it stays \n, not a newline
cmd = ['printf', r"%s\n"] + glob.glob('*.*', root_dir=path)
result = subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True, cwd=path)

Of course, once you've done all this, you should realize it's all pointless, because all you're doing is collecting the names of things in the folder, which Python can already do for you:
import glob

directory_contents = sorted(glob.glob("*.*", root_dir='path/to/folder'))

or if *.* is intended to mean "all files" (as a sort of hack where you assume file names have extensions, and directories don't), you really want:
import os

directory_contents = sorted(entry.name for entry in os.scandir('path/to/folder')
                                       if entry.is_file())

which makes directory_contents a sorted list of all the file names in the folder matching your requirements (you want to sort it because the listing order is not useful, and people can get hung up thinking the listing order is deterministic, when it is not). You can make it a str with the names newline separated if you really want to ("\n".join(directory_contents)), but that's highly unlikely to be useful.

Before anyone chimes in in the comments: shell=True is dangerous, non-portable, and a source of all sorts of problems. I'm not going to recommend switching to shell=True except in extreme circumstances, and this circumstance doesn't even require a subprocess in the first place.

Thank you for explaining this, that all makes sense and is great to know for future context. For this particular problem, I'll stick to os.listdir() -- seems like you agree it's the most appropriate. Really appreciate the breakdown!

FWIW, if I try directory_contents = sorted(glob.glob("*.*", root_dir='path/to/folder')) I get TypeError: glob() got an unexpected keyword argument 'root_dir' ...maybe a version issue on my end?

@user3064637: Ugh, yes. root_dir was apparently added in 3.10. I'd actually recommend avoiding os.listdir for most uses; os.scandir is both more powerful and more performant. os.listdir is basically only for when you know you want all the names in the directory at once, don't need the full paths, and don't care whether they're files, directories, etc.

Ah, good to know. Thanks!
